# Eclipse autocomplete problems

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

I use Map a lot in Java with eclipse. e.g.

```
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

then when I am ready to add something with put:

```
 String key = null;
 String value = null;
 // somewhere before the put, key and value get populated with Strings
 map.put(key, value);
```

the problem is, every time I type "map.put", Eclipse autocomplete changes it to "map.compute()" so I have to edit and remove the "com" and the "e".

I looked at Window -> preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist  but nothing was apparent.  I could, I suppose, turn off all content assist, but that would be like "throwing the baby out with the bath water".  There are a lot of useful things in the content assist.

My Eclipse:

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Build id: 20181214-0600
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 1.8.0_144

How can I fix eclipse so it will make the correct suggestions like it did in previous versions?

Comment: I have Neon, but the setting might be similar. In the Content Assist settings, what is the value set to `Sort proposals`? For me, mine is set to `by relevance` (which I've never changed), but I reproduced your problem when I changed that setting to `alphabetically`.

Comment: strange, but I looked and I guess my version thinks "compute" is more relevant than "put" for a map, even when set to relevant instead of alphabetical.  As a matter of fact, either way it is the same, unless there is some other setting that I need to do?

Comment: No other setting that I know. Maybe ensure that you've clicked 'apply', maybe restart Eclipse afterwards to see if that might change anything. Taking a look around, your issue seem to be a [common complaint](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1096932/) that they call "code recommenders". I might suggest to try the Photon version of Eclipse, as it seems like the version you mentioned is not yet named, at least based on [this wikipedia info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Releases) table.

Comment: It started up with "relevant" already selected.  I will check out your Photon suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

None of the proposed solutions worked for me. What fixed it was to disable "Show substring matches" (in `Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist`).

It should be considered that this will break the functionality to just type a random part of the desired reference, e.g. typing "PreparedStatement" no longer leads to `OraclePreparedStatement`. A feature that I don't care about, but this is obviously a matter of personal preference.

In my opinion, the name of that option is a slight misnomer since the substring aspect only applies to leading and not to trailing content.

Update: In Eclipse 2020-06, there is no longer an option "Show substring matches". In its place there is "Show subword matches", but even when disabled,  suggestions for typing `map.put` still include `compute`. At least when sorted by relevance rather than alphabetically, `put` is listed in the suggestions before `compute`.

Answer (score 3):

> Window->Preferences
>   Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced

Unchecking "Java Proposals (Task-Focused)" and instead checking regular  "Java Type Proposals" fixed the problem for me.  I'm using Eclipse for Enterprise Java Developers 2019-03 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be due to the unfortunate decision to remove 'Code Recommenders' going forward from 2018-12

> "... Code Recommenders will unfortunately not make it into 2018-12."
>
> https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=542689

The solution currently is to add it manually from the marketplace.

```
Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Search for 'Code Recommenders'
```

There are no guarantees it will work for Java 11+.

Once installed, you'll have to:

- restart Eclipse
- close the 'Autocomplete installed' information page
- attempt autocomplete once and select the top option that's something like 'Autocomplete enabled'

Finally attempt autocomplete again, this time it should work as expected

**Update:** It appears Code Recommenders has been archived due to lack of maintainers. When you try to download it, you will get a 404. Hopefully this is temporary.